# A point of style with try/catch

Tags: java, coding-style, predicate

I was wondering if this approach was correct :

```
public ITask getState()
{
    statePredicate[Some predicate definition];
    ITask nextRunnable = null;
try {
    nextRunnable = Iterables.find((Iterable)queue, statePredicate);
} 
    catch (NoSuchElementException e) 
    {}
return nextRunnable;
}
```

The points on which I am wondering are :

- should the predicate be cached as a member of the class ?
- I do nothing with the catch, I do not even log it because it is
  normal for my app to not find anything.
- t return null because I do a final return.

Thank you for your input !
        -

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a serious question or not. Surely you realize that swallowing an exception is a [well known anti pattern](http://www.rockstarprogrammer.org/post/2007/jun/09/java-exception-antipatterns/)?

Comment: Yes I know :), that's precisely the reason why I was asking : I should not swallow it, yet, in my case, it is very common to raise this exception. The solution of Jesper looks promising, I am going to have a look at it (since yes, I am using Guava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If the predicate is always the same, I would make it a `static final` class member.

2) There is also a version of `Iterables.find` that you can specify a default value to (assuming you're using Google Guava). Then you don't need to deal with the `NoSuchElementException` at all.

3) Is there a reason to cast `queue` to `Iterable`? If this is not necessary, then don't cast.

```
class MyClass {
    private static final Predicate STATE_PREDICATE = new Predicate<ITask>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(ITask input) {
            // ... your code here
        }
    };

    public ITask getState() {
        return Iterables.find(queue, STATE_PREDICATE, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ideas. I indeed removed the cast on queue as it was useless and defined my predicate as final and also used the overload for Guava find :)

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is really the usual case in your approach than you should put at least a comment into the catch area to make clear for everyone who reads the code that it was intentional and not a mistake. In my opinion returning Null is something different, but it some circumstanced not avoidable.